# How to connect Jira using Atlassian.SDK from .Net application (c#)

Tags: c#, .net, jira, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I am using Atlassian.SDK Jira SDk to connect Jira from my .NET application .
To connect JIRA I have the following calls but it does not connect to Jira properly .I am getting unauthorized access exception

```
        var  jira = Jira.CreateRestClient("https://xxxxx.atlassian.net", "xxxxx.xx@xxx.com", "xxx@xxx");


        CreateIssue(jira);

    public async void CreateIssue(Jira jira) {

        var issue = jira.CreateIssue("RBT");
        issue.Type = "Bug";
        issue.Priority = "Major";
        issue.Summary = "Issue Summary";

        await issue.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

which is the correct way to establish the connection .Also,How can i query all the created Issues

Comment: Are you sure your email is your username?

Comment: yes ,Through Email I am connecting to Jira Portal

Answer (score 1):

With the assumption that you are using a Jira cloud instance (based on your instance name), basic authentication using password have been deprecated (see [announcement](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/deprecation-notice-basic-auth-and-cookie-based-auth/)), be sure to use `email:apiToken` pair when doing basic auth.